# Is it possible to change the fishing sound?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Fishing in World of Warcraft involves casting and then waiting for the fishing bobber to move, which is accompanied by the sound of water splashing.

[image: Fishing]

I used to use a modification that disabled all of the casting sounds in World of Warcraft, which consisted of replacing all of the associated game sounds with silent files, stored in a folder called 'Sound' within the 'Data' folder - so I imagine that this is possible, but does anybody know how to change the water splashing sound that indicates you've caught something?

Comment: Are the sound files named? You could try replacing them one at a time to get the desired result. A similar mod did the same thing with the hunter and gun sounds, I replaced the files with a silenced m4 from counter-strike :P.

Comment: One at a time sounds like a bad idea... There are over 50000 different sound files and while some of them are reasonably named the others really aren't that descriptively named at all :P

Comment: I was just suggesting that if some of them were named fishing something or other you can use that as a starting point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Sound.MPQ file contains these four files relating to the splashing:

```
Sound\Spells\FishingBobber_ver2_1.ogg
Sound\Spells\FishingBobber_ver2_2.ogg
Sound\Spells\FishingBobber_ver2_3.ogg
Sound\Spells\Tradeskills\FishBite.ogg
```

I can't quite tell if all of them are still being used, but I'm pretty certain there aren't any more than these.

Override them as usual, by placing new OGG files with these paths in your Data directory.

Comment: Just a side question, Michael, what would be your choice of software to use to produce .ogg sound files?

Comment: There's always [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/download/windows). Fine freeware audio editor with many possible output types.

Comment: @James: I would also use Audacity, like Terrance mentions, since it can output directly to .ogg and it makes everything as simple as can be. If that's not an option (for some reason), I'd just grab the [vorbis-tools](http://www.xiph.org/downloads/) to get an encoder and run a .wav file through it.

Comment: Yeah I used Audacity to make my replacement files... never going to miss a fishing cast again!